# How to extract the sub string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string something like

```
when (update [page1] [desc]) and match ([desc] is not null), then (Rule:setvalue; SourceValue:[ign [desc]]; TargetField:[desc2])
```

Do anybody have good way to extract the the 3 strings:

```
(update [page1] [desc])
([desc] is not null)
(Rule:setvalue; SourceValue:[ign [desc]]; TargetField:[desc2])
```

the 3 part may be any characters. Java regex is also fine to implement. but add the keyword 'when', 'and match', 'then' may make scene.

Comment: Can the round brackets be nested, also?

Comment: Yes, the round brackets may be nested

Comment: Just write a loop to keep track of the number of opening brackets.

Comment: @C.c: What output for `the (quick (brown) (fox jumps (over) the) lazy) dog` do you expect, then?

Comment: We don't have this kinds of statement, the format is when (something) and match (something), then (something), something may contain any characters, including round brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "when (update [page1] [desc]) and match ([desc] is not null), then (Rule:setvalue; SourceValue:[ign [desc]]; TargetField:[desc2])";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
(update [page1] [desc])
([desc] is not null)
(Rule:setvalue; SourceValue:[ign [desc]]; TargetField:[desc2])
```

If you dont want braces in your output :

Change:

```
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

To:

```
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: The regex is a bit redundant: `"\\(.+?\\)"` is enough. But note that it will match `()(text)` in one match.

Comment: the round brackets may be nested, so () may not make sense so much, can use keyword 'when', 'and match', 'then' to match it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern:

```
String regex = "\\([^)]++\\)";
```